# How to embed the youtube player but not using iframe approach?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, html5-video

Is it possible to using a div to wrap the youtube player instead of iframe? Since the iframe is block by chrome by default. Thanks

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/user/ThePianoGuys" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: The Youtube player is hosted on youtube.com, thus the need for an iframe. If you don't want to use an iframe, you'd have to have your own player app that would have to have access to the youtube video stream (which I don't think is possible ATM).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the youtube api. You can add different arguments to embed, like I did with "showinfo=0". Here is a example code.

```
<object width="320" height="180">
              <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/9bZkp7q19f0&amp;showinfo=0">
              <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
              <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/9bZkp7q19f0&amp;showinfo=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="320" height="180">
</object>
```

Comment: Just remember that this method is deprecated (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player).